# how to get second level data from Stripe JSON object

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I have  function that is able to retrieve level 1 array data, but not level 2 in the return JSON string following a charge.

```
else if(!empty($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_BUY_CODE'])){
       $pcharge = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
       "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
       "plan" => $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_BUY_CODE'],
       "email" => $_SESSION["SESS_EMAIL"]
       ));
    echo "My customer id is: " . $pcharge->id;
    echo'<br>';
    $stuff = json_decode($pcharge->subscriptions);
    var_dump($stuff);
```

Actual JSON return string:
[JSON](https://bpaste.net/show/18641992272a)

the output from the above code is:

My customer `id` is: `cus_6cvCQdpdhmQlGe`
`NULL`

expected output:

My customer `id` is: `cus_6cvCQdpdhmQlGe`
`1`

I have tried:

```
$stuff = $pcharge->subscriptions[0];
$stuff = $pcharge->subscriptions['total_count'];
$stuff = json_decode($pcharge->subscriptions);
```

and  few loops
I get either `NULL` or some other error indicating the programmer doesn't know what he is doing.

How do I get to `level 2` and `level 3` data in the Stripe JSON return string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `json_decode()`, the Stripe API does all the decoding internally. You just need to access the objects and arrays that it returns.

```
$pcharge = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    "plan" => $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_BUY_CODE'],
    "email" => $_SESSION["SESS_EMAIL"]
));
echo "My customer id is: " . $pcharge->id;
echo'<br>';
$stuff = $pcharge->subscriptions;
echo "Subscription count is: " . count($stuff->data); // total_count isn't returned by default
```

If you want to access the subscriptions, use `$stuff->data[$i]`.

Comment: I tried  ->  echo "Subscription count is: " . count($stuff->total_count); and ->  echo "Subscription count is: " . count($stuff->data); and a few variations. The best I can get is a zero and not a 1.

Comment: Since you just created the customer, and haven't added any subscriptions, why do you expect anything to be in the subscription list?

Comment: then you answered the wrong question. screwup in reverse   ;)